# location access permission alert disappears after phone locked

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I'm Using CLLocationManager to monitor user location in my app. Steps to produce the issue are listed down:-

1. When i invoke CLLocationmanager's requestwheninuseauthorization method for the first time, it presents the location access permission alert & i don't make a choice on allow or don't allow buttons.
2. Now if phone is locked due to being idle for some time or interrupted by a phone call.
3. I unlocks the phone & see the my app which was already running in foreground with location access permission dialogue, now after unlocking phone i don't find the location access permission alert  on the screen within my app. It just disappears, despite the fact that neither i rejected nor accepted to provide location access.

What could be the reason for that & how can i resolve this issue, else what could be a workaround as it seems an issue with the iOS. As per my requirement user must provide location access before using my app.

Comment: The allow app to use location is only displayed once. After this you must handle the authorization state your self. So once your app come to the foreground check the state. When `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` you can use `requestWhenInUseAuthorization ` again. Any other state where you cant access the location you should redirect the user to the settings screen. Also I would suggest you submit a bug report to Apple about the dialog disappearing.

Comment: Apart from the dialogue disappearing issue i don't have any confusion in using location manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted by Sandeep , I have added observer of the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification by using below code in viewDidLoad: method of my viewcontroller.

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(didBecomeActive) 
                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
                                     object:nil];
```

Now i have again presented the location authorisation dialogue in my didBecomeActive method of viewcontroller.

```
    - (void)didBecomeActive {
// Here put your conditions to check that user hasn't already authorised or rejected the location access permissions.
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
```

So now whenever user unlocks the device the authorization dialogue is always there due to above mentioned implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to access the location info you can use this to test if user has granted the location access permission or not :)

```
BOOL isAuthorized = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse;
    BOOL isTurnedOn = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
     if (isAuthorized || !isTurnedOn) {
         [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
     }
     else {
         [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
     }
```

Comment: Sandeep, You haven't understood my question. Apart from the dialogue disappearing issue i don't have any confusion in using location manager.

Comment: @ios-geek : Your question stated "else what could be a workaround as it seems an issue with the iOS". Hence I have written an answer because the location usage authorization alert appears only once and if user miss that because of his device being locked then when app comes to foreground or whenever your app tries to access locations info you should check if permission exists and if not should show alert again to him to give him one more chance to provide it

Comment: But when iPhone unlocked the user is on the same page where i requested the location permission. As the view controller is already loaded now i don't get a call back of phone unlock in any view lifecycle method, Now how can i  execute requestWhenInUseAuthorization again without an event callback ? this was what i mean by workaround. Can you suggest something in this regard?

Comment: @iOSGeek : You can add  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didBecomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification  object:nil]; to your ViewController this will trigger your code everytime your app becomes active which includes unlocking the device as well :) You can always check location status in the method didBecomeActive

Comment: Thanks a lot ! this is what i was expecting.

Comment: Issue resolved . Thanks @SandeepBhandari for above approach . Inside did become active addObserver function work well but not getting why requestWhenInUseAuthorization() not working in scene delegate sceneWillEnterForeground method ?